# VBA - How do I send new line command (\n) or tab command (\t) to a textbox.textrange.text of a PowerPointS Shape

Tags: vba, excel

```
SlideNumber = 1
Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNumber)

For y = 1 To oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count
    MsgBox oPPTSlide.Shapes(y).Name
Next

With oPPTSlide.Shapes("Title 1")
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _ 
               "Operations Monthly Report\n" & _
               "April " & _
               "2014"
End With
```

This is the code I have now. The "\n" does cause the text-box I am editing to start a new line. Is it possible? The code, in its context, is working perfectly. The exact text is sent to the text-box though, not two lines of text.

Comment: You can use the constants `vbLf` and `vbTab` or Chr(10)/Chr(9) Eg `"Operations Monthly Report" & vbLf & "April 2014"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "\n" in Vba instead you should use VbNewLine or VbCrLf or Vblf

Replace this

```
SlideNumber = 1
Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNumber)

For y = 1 To oPPTSlide.Shapes.Count
    MsgBox oPPTSlide.Shapes(y).Name
Next

With oPPTSlide.Shapes("Title 1")
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _ 
               "Operations Monthly Report" & VbCrLf & _
               "April " & _
               "2014"
End With
```

Comment: For me, this only shows the newline sign - it doesn't put the text on a new line,

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem where the vbNewLine didn't work in the UserForm, but I fixed it by checking the textBox properties and making sure multi-line is true. Give that a try.